# How to create temporary table using multiple views

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a temporary table using five different views, each one has the same column names but different values.

I'm using MySQL5. So far I've tried to run the following:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp`
SELECT *
FROM `first_view`, `second_view`, `third_view`, `fourth_view`, `fifth_view`
```

But then I get an error telling me that the column `Name` is duplicated. Changing it to:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp`
SELECT `first_view`.Name AS Test
FROM `first_view`, `second_view`, `third_view`, `fourth_view`, `fifth_view`
```

Just creates a temporary table with the `Name` column, nothing else.

To briefly demonstrate what I mean, here's the structure of the views:

```sql
View `first_view`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data1  |    494  |
---------------------

View `second_view`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data2  |    78   |
---------------------


View `third_view`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data3  |    12   |
---------------------


View `fourth_view`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data4  |    752  |
---------------------

View `fifth_view`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data5  |    909  |
---------------------
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a temporary table with the following structure:

```sql
Temporary table `temp`:
---------------------
|   Name  |    Qty  |
---------------------
|  data1  |    494  |
|  data2  |     78  |
|  data3  |     12  |
|  data4  |    752  |
|  data5  |    909  |
---------------------
```

Is there a way to achieve this? If so, how should the SQL statement look like to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, since all views have the same number of columns

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp`
SELECT * FROM `first_view` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `second_view` UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `third_view` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `fourth_view` UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `fifth_view`
```

Comment: Was just about to post this very solution.

Comment: Glad to help, can you set this as correct answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` may help you to combine all tables data into a single table.
Like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTemp AS (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2)
```